# How to measure the file download speed in another country

Tags: apache, performance, page-speed

Now I have a dir with about 5000 files (images) in it and I concerned if this amount will significantly slowdown speed of page load with this images. I'd like to test the load speed of an image from this big directory in comparison with a dir with a small amount of files. The problem is that I am in Russia but the web-served is located in US and dedicated for US users. So how do I check the speed of download from another country?

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: There are a number of sites that will test the load speed, one of which is [here](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) - just be sure to use URLs to the files you want to test, and you can select different locations to test from.